# RewriteRule Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rule that redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS except from one particular directory. In this case named "sample", like the following:

```
example.com -> https://example.com
example.com/index.html -> https://example.com/index.html
example.com/sample/ -> example.com/sample/
```

I have tryed to modify the common code for redirecting to HTTPS but I can get it to work properly, here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (www.)?%{HTTP_HOST}/?(?!/sample) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

By Regular expressions I'm trying to ignore the "sample" directory but it neither redirect the "index.html" page.
What is missing or how can I do it correctly?

Thanksfully, V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+sample [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```